# How to memory map a part of a binary file?

Tags: python, binaryfiles, mmap

I am using mmap library and want to memory map a specific part of a binary file.
From the `mmap` help I get that the `mmap.mmap` has the following fields:

```
mmap(fileno, length, access=ACCESS_WRITE, offset)
```

So I am trying to memory map the file from 10th byte till the end of the file.

```
with open(fileName, "r+b") as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, offset=16)
```

but when I try to do this I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 1132] The base address or the file offset specified does not have the proper alignment
```

Have anyone done something like that before and/or have any ideas what I am doing wrong here?
Most probably it is the way I am using the `offset`.

Comment: "Alignment" indicates that an offset of 10 or 16 isn't possible with your architecture.  Try `0`, that should work.  Maybe just multiples of 4096 are allowed or so.

Comment: @Alfe: and maybe it is actually described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html). Oh wait, it is: "offset must be a multiple of the PAGESIZE or ALLOCATIONGRANULARIT"

Comment: I tried with 4096 (which supposed to be the standard value) but got the same error. By printing the mmap.ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY value I get 65536 and it doesn't let me giving an offset of that value (ValueError: mmap offset is greater than file size)

Comment: exactly as @usr2564301 mentioned... So the actual question is "if there is a general way to mmap a specific range of bytes of a binary file"

Comment: Seems to me that to do it generally would boil down to adding the offset to accesses to the `mmap` object. How does your code **use** `mm` after it's created?

Comment: I am encoding the mmap object to a bytearray and comparing it with a previous state, so that I detect if something has been changed to it.
So I guess I can try to compare a specific range of bytes of the mmap object and that would do the trick

Comment: Please [edit] this question and add some code that is runnable and does that (while reproducing the problem). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I propose to use 0 as offset (I already proposed that way up).  Then you can access the whole file from the beginning on.  But of course you do not have to access the complete file.  Just access the bytes from 10 onwards.